# Trying to get an array to contain information from a column on another worksheet in VBA

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2013

I'm very new to VBA and I have been using the below code to reorder columns to a specified order in the nams array.

What I would like to do is instead of having the list of columns written into the code is take the list from a range on another worksheet to make the code more flexible going forward but I'm not sure where to start. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

```
Dim rng As Range
Dim i As Integer
Dim J As Integer
Dim Temp
Dim nams As Variant
Dim F
Dim Dex As Integer
nams = Array("RequestCode", "Contact", "OpenDate", "ClosedDate")
Set rng = Range("A1").CurrentRegion
For i = 1 To rng.Columns.Count
    For J = i To rng.Columns.Count
        For F = 0 To UBound(nams)
            If nams(F) = rng(J) Then Dex = F: Exit For
       Next F
        If F < i Then
            Temp = rng.Columns(i).Value
            rng(i).Resize(rng.Rows.Count) = rng.Columns(J).Value
            rng(J).Resize(rng.Rows.Count) = Temp
        End If
    Next J
 Next I
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Dim nams() As Variant
nams = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1:A5")
```

This will read the values of the specified range into your nams() array which indexes at 1, not 0. Keep in mind, doing this method always results in a two dimensional array, so to get your third value for example you will have to do something like `nams(3,1)`.

Comment: Thanks SandPiper! I've updated the code to read a range into the array but I'm getting a "subscript out of range" error on the "If nams(F) = rng(J)..." line. Do you have any idea how I can fix this?

Comment: Check the indices, you are starting from 0, not 1. It should be `For F = 1 To UBound(nams)`.

Comment: I just tried your suggestion but got the same subscript out of range error. Could it be because this is a 2D array?

Comment: See edit. I kept getting empty values on my end when I tried it until I changed it to `Sheets("Sheet1")`. It does not give an error on my end when `F=1`, I get `nams(F,1)` equal to the value in A1.

Comment: This was working fine and ran through multiple loops but then the `rng(i).Resize(rng.Rows.Count) = rng.Columns(J).Value` line caused an Overflow error. Any suggestions?